# Current Amplification

Tags: transistors, current, boost

I have a DAC that outputs between 0-5V range but lacks the current output, that I do need to get more out of it, it provides approximately 10mA at tops. I need to boost the current by a transistor but to choose it I need some advice. What I am trying to say is that, whatever output I give from DAC, I need the same voltage but should be capable of providing higher currents upto 500mA. To achieve this I wanted to ask to experienced users regarding the topic.

Comment: Do you really want to use a transistor? A voltage following op-amp sounds much nearer to your requirements

Comment: I wanted to go with a transistor because it's has much higher switching characteristics than op-amp's as far as I know.

Comment: @DavidSilveria "Higher switching characteristics" Higher what? What characteristic? Higher current? You can use op-amps with one, or two external pass transistor so you have the op-amps linearity but the transistor's output current.

Comment: What load do you want to drive with your 0-5V output, and how accurate does it have to be?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly you essentially want to boost the current capability. While a transistor can do this, there's even better when you use an op amp and transistor to boost current. Shown below is a current boosting circuit that increases the output current of op amp via transistor and thus increases current capability from input of circuit. Why use an op amp you may ask. Op amp has high input impedance (much higher than a transistor buffer) which be useful to isolate output of DAC from your powerful load. Also the op amp with feedback will essentially make the output voltage equal to the input voltage. While I understand your concern with switching frequency ( I think you really mean gain bandwidth), there are op amps that have higher frequency performance.  Note that you can utilize a high frequency op amp, high current BJT, and voltage supply for op amp and bjt that is about 1V or 2V higher than Vin max.  OP amp can be LT6202 or THS4031 which has 100Mhz gain bandwidth for example but can be op amps with higher Gain bandwidth. [image: Op amp buffer bjt]

Image Source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-1/

If your output needs to be positive and negative. You can use a circuit like this:

[image]

image source:https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-2/

For selecting an appropriate BJT:

Voltage requirement: If your system runs from 12V for example , a BJT with VCE voltage rating of three times the voltage is sufficient, ie 36V or higher. A few common VCE ratings are 40 and 60V.

Current Requirement: If your load will consume 500mA max then a transistor with at least three times that should suffice. For example 1.5A transistor will do.

Note that this is one way to determine a ratings for transistor and is based on providing plenty of margin for voltage and current.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the op-amp recommendation. I will first try to simulate this simple circuit if I can find or create necessary components to see if I get the desirable output. What do you think about the propagation delays in your example ? I mean on what orders of latency should I expect between Vin and Vout ?

Comment: @David Silveria, for the op amps provided, it’s hard to tell what the propagation delay would be. This would also depend on your signal. However if I mention the AD817, op amp, refer to figure 23 in datasheet, you can see a 30ns delay between the input and output a for it to reach steady state value. This also includes slew rate consideration. I would recommend you to simulate the circuit to get an idea of what your signal output would look like.

Comment: How about if I want to limit the current to 500mA where load can draw more from it, what kind of configuration would it be ? Thanks